# How to test getting parameters on the Rest service using the Post method

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, integration-testing, spring-resttemplate

I'm trying to test getting parameters for processing a request using the Post method

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class InnerRestController {

…
    @PostMapping("createList")
    public ItemListId createList(@RequestParam String strListId,
@RequestParam String strDate) {


…
        return null;
    }
}
```

- test method

*variant 1*

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class InnerRestControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void innerCreatePublishList() {

        String url = "http://localhost:" + this.port;

        String uri = "/api/createList";

        String listStr = "kl";

        String strDate = "10:21";

        URI uriToEndpoint = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(url)
                .path(uri)
                .queryParam("strListId", listStr)
                .queryParam("strDate ", strDate)
                .build()
                .encode()
                .toUri();

        ResponseEntity< ItemListId > listIdResponseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, uriToEndpoint, ItemListId.class);


    }
}
```

*variant 2*

```java
@Test
void createList() {

        String uri = "/api/createList";

        String listStr = "kl";

        String strDate = "10:21";

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(uri)
                .queryParam("strListId", listStr)
                .queryParam("strDate ", strDate);

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("strListId", listStr);//request parameters
    map.put("strDate", strDate);


    ResponseEntity< ItemListId > listIdResponseEntity =
            restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, map, ItemListId.class);


}
```

**Update_1**

In my project exceptions is handled thus:

- dto

```java
public final class ErrorResponseDto {

    private  String errorMsg;

    private  int status;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    LocalDateTime timestamp;

...
```

- handler

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionAdviceHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = PublishListException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDto> handleGenericPublishListDublicateException(PublishListException e) {

        ErrorResponseDto error = new ErrorResponseDto(e.getMessage());
        error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        error.setStatus((HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value()));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }   

}
```

In methods, where necessary, I throw a specific exception...

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
> Required String parameter 'strListId' is not present]

Who knows what the error is. Please explain what you need to add here and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look on [declarations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) of `postEntity`:

```
postForEntity(URI url, Object request, Class<T> responseType)
...
postForEntity(String url, Object request, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables)
```

As you can see, first argument is either `URI` or `String with uriVariables`, but second argument is always request entity.

In you first variant you put `uri` String as URI and then pass `uriToEndpoint` as request entity, pretending that it is request object. Correct solution will be:

```java
ResponseEntity<ItemListId> listIdResponseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(uriToEndpoint, null, ItemListId.class);
```

---

*Addressing your comments.*

If server responded with HTTP 409, `RestTemplate` will throw exception with content of your `ErrorResponseDto`. You can catch `RestClientResponseException` and deserialize server response stored in exception. Something like this:

```java
try {
  ResponseEntity<ItemListId> listIdResponseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(uriToEndpoint, null, 
  ItemListId.class);
  
  ...
} catch(RestClientResponseException e) {
  byte[] errorResponseDtoByteArray  = e.getResponseBodyAsByteArray();
  
  // Deserialize byte[] array using Jackson
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ivan Babanin. I already get a request into an endpoint Rest-service. But , when There will be to throw an exception, Then excetpionHandler must be to answer - {
    "errorMsg": "PublishList with parameter values such as` key `and` id ' is already installed.",
    "status": 409,
    "timestamp": "2020-08-21 11:08:43"
} , but I only get - status code. What can I must add , and that  I would can to get - {
    "errorMsg": "PublishList with parameter values such as` key `and` id ' is already installed.",
    "status": 409,
    "timestamp": "2020-08-21 11:08:43"
}

Comment: The container ( on side backend ) for this type of json has a different type - ErrorResponseDto . As I understand it, you need to return a generic type ?

Comment: Ivan Babanin, An exception catch in test method, don't  fit in my case (see above, I added info...), an exception that will appear, It will  catch by interceptor. In the test method I only get ready answer in json format.